# Can't secure MySQL (MariaDB) connection with SSL (mysql installed on NAS Synology)

Tags: c#, mysql, ssl, mariadb, synology

A few question about MySQL (5.5.47-MariaDB - Source distribution) running on Synology NAS. I have build some application in C#, which is speaking with this mysql. It works fine. 
My problem is to make SSL Connection. I read, and read a lot of tutorials, mysql website etc. I think i understand conception: 
Create certs (with openssl.exe), put this files into mysql direcory (like etc/mysql ??), edit configuration files and convert this files from PEM to PFX (because PEM is not supported in .NET). Next edit user in mysql to: requier SSL. In connection string (C#) add path to pfx file.

But i have a problem:
In synology NAS i can't find  my.cnf or my.ini. I don't know where i should look for this. 
Everyone in other posts says: edit my.cnf or edit my.ini. But i cant find this files. 
So, where should i put PEM files (ca-cert.pem, server-cert.pem, server-key.pem)? 
Which file i should edit, to say, that i want to secure connection with SSL?

And the last question. Secure connection with SSL it concern all databases in mysql server or just one db, which i choosen?

Thanks for everyone,
Darek

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you have a folder named data under your MARIA n.n.nn primary folder.  With my.cnf or my.ini.

This link

```
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-ssl-connection-issues/
```

should be helpful for your SSL questions.

Comment: Ok, done. I found the "my.cnf" file via SSH in synology. Thanks for help.